# python equivalent of the R table(iris$Species)

Tags: python

I want to convert R code to Python. i got the iris data sets with pandas in python but I don't know how to get the same result. how can i got the same code in python?

```
R Code 
> table(iris$Species)
setosa versicolor virginica
  50       50        50
```

Comment: R is built around data analysis and visualization. Python is built to be general purpose. There is no built-in equivalent for R's `table` function in Python. But you can look at Python data science modules, such as `pandas`, `plotly` or `matplotlib`. You can do this pretty easily with `pandas`.

Comment: See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-basics-of-pandas-using-iris-dataset/

Comment: @KonradRudolph you are 100% right, and the link I gave is not about iris dataset. Page title is: Basics of Pandas using "USING" Iris Dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something similar.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd

iris = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('iris', 'datasets')
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data)

iris_train, iris_test = train_test_split(df, train_size = 0.7, stratify=df["Species"])

data = iris_train.rename(columns={"variety": "Species"})
data = data.groupby("Species")
print(data.size())
```

```
Species
setosa        35
versicolor    35
virginica     35
dtype: int64
```